# Tomar valor de rangeSlider OnChange con click

Tags: javascript, script

rangeSlider .Quiero jalar el valor de on Change y mostrarlo en cierto campo cuando le hagan click a un boton boton

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$("#range-slider-1").on("change", function () {
        var $inp = $(this);
        var from = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
        var from2 = $inp.data("from"); // reading input data-from attribute

        console.log(from, from2); 
    });
            function miclick(){
            document.getElementById("monto_inicial").innerHTML =from;
           }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo importante es hacer la variable `from` una variable global.

```js
var from;// la variable `from` es una variable global.

$("#range-slider-1").on("change", function () {
        var $inp = $(this);
            from = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
        var from2 = $inp.data("from"); // reading input data-from attribute

        console.log(from, from2); 
    });
function miclick(){document.getElementById("monto_inicial").innerHTML =from;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="range-slider-1" data-from = "100" />
<button onclick="miclick()">botón</button><span id="monto_inicial"></span>
```